# For loop ending after one iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

So I had this original piece of code to replace words in a "fill in the blanks" game for a a python class I'm taking:

```
while victory == False:
    round0 = ''
    round1 = ''
    round2 = ''
    round3 = ''
    round4 = ''
    round5 = ''
    answerx = listchange()
    while round0 != answerx[0]:
        print ''.join(glvl)
        round0 = raw_input('What word is ___(0)___? ')
    while round1 != answerx[1]:
        print ''.join(num_replace(glvl,0))
        round1 = raw_input('What word is ___(1)___? ')
    while round2 != answerx[2]:
        print ''.join(num_replace(num_replace(glvl,0),1))
        round2 = raw_input('What word is ___(2)___? ')
    while round3 != answerx[3]:
        print ''.join(num_replace(num_replace(num_replace(glvl,0),1),2))
        round3 = raw_input('What word is ___(3)___ ')
    print ''.join(num_replace(num_replace(num_replace(num_replace(glvl,0),1),2),3))
    print 'Congratulations!'
    victory = True
```

It was rejected because it only applies to four blanks in the question and my code should work no matter how many blank spots are in it.

So now I've been working on remaking it and been having a lot of trouble. Here is my most successful attempt so far:

```
for i in glvl:
    glvlstr = ''.join(glvl)
    answerx = listchange()
    counter = 0
    if i == blank_list[counter]:
        print glvlstr
        askq = raw_input('What word is ' + i + '? ')
        if askq == answerx:
            glvl[i] = askq
            glvlstr = ''.join(glvl)
    counter += 1
```

It starts fine and runs this:

```
Please select a difficulty level: easy, normal, hard, maximum-carnage, bonus-level: easy
In ___(0)___ if you want to pass the W3 ___(1)___ make sure you ___(2)___ your ___(3)___!
What word is ___(0)___? HTML
```

But at that point it just quits. It should then print out:

```
In HTML if yuou want to pass the W3 ___(1)___ make sure you ___(2)___ your ___(3)___!
What word is ___(1)___?
```

and then cycle through word by word replacing them until it is done.

Comment: If you need to see any other part of the code let me know.

Comment: You clearly know how to write a loop, what is stopping you from doing that here?

Comment: @Natcat Yeah that's basically my question, what is stopping me from doing that here?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice it was all in a loop already. I'll give you a hint: A for loop isn't the loop you are looking for here, a while loop would do the job much more elegantly

Answer (score 0):

You set counter to zero,  check the if statement, then increment the counter. But on the next iteration you reset counter to zero,  so the if is always checking for counter = 0. Initialize counter before the for loop. Seems like this might be your problem.

Comment: I tried that already but I get this error: IndexError: list index out of range referencing the "if i ==blank_counter[counter]:" line

Comment: Yeah, not sure what's in your blank_list, but if you get that error then there are more elements in glvl than blank_list so you increment counter beyond the end of blank_list... Do you expect blank_list to have the same number of elements as glvl?

Answer (score 0):

As you are incrementing `counter` for every iteration, you can clean it us a bit as follows

```
for counter,i in enumerate(glvl):
    # glvlstr = ''.join(glvl) unnecessary
    answerx = listchange() # what does this do?
    if i == blank_list[counter]:
        print ''.join(glvl)
        askq = raw_input('What word is ' + i + '? ')
        if askq == answerx:
            glvl[i] = askq
            # glvlstr = ''.join(glvl) unnecessary
```

Comment: Listchange() looks at what level you are playing (wasy, normal, etc) and returns the correct answer list

Comment: So the answer list to easy would look like this: ['HTML','validator','close','tags']

Comment: This is the error I get:      for i,counter in glvl:
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: @SteveMedley **Sorry**. There is a mistake. Edited it. if `glvl` is a `list`. `enumerate` will work correctly.